# Democratic People's Republic of Korea

Tags: word-choice, idioms, figures-of-speech

Is there a term for a word like *Democratic* in *Democratic People's Republic of Korea*?

The key point here is that the word is being used *precisely because it's false*.

It has something in common with a *fiat*, but that, I think, is a declaration of something in an attempt to *make* it true, whereas here it's presumably in order to *convince* people it's true.

The best I can come up with is *propaganda*, but that seems too specific somehow.

Is there a better term?

Comment: you could parody it with "Demonistic ..." perhaps?

Comment: *Saying doesn't make it so.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Oxymoronic' comes to mind. Or you could say, 'the incongruously named Democratic People's Republic..."

Answer (score -2):

The same goes for *[Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic)*:

> A republic is a form of government in which power resides in the people, and the government is ruled by elected leaders run according to law, rather than inherited or appointed (such as through inheritance or divine mandate).

[RationalWiki](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/North_Korea) says of the Democratic People's Republic of Korea:

> The country's official name (DPRK) is anything but accurate. Amusingly enough, the definition of the word "democratic" according to the Oxford English Dictionary is "a system of government by the whole population of a state," and the definition of "republic" is "a state in which supreme power is held by the people," meaning that North Korea's full name means "People-ruled People's People-ruled State of Korea." In reality, North Korea is neither a democracy nor a republic: it is a full-on dictatorship — specifically, an absolute hereditary monarchy.

The choice of name is to display a sense of legitimacy, so could be termed something like a *faux-legitimising* name.

Comment: You should never cite RationalWiki as a source...

Comment: @Milliarde89: Why not? Do you disagree with the quoted part?